# Local history configuration in IntelliJ IDEA 11

Tags: intellij-idea

In previous versions of IDEA I was able to set how many days back the Local History feature would keep the changes in the source files.
For some reason, I cannot find this in IDEA 11.1.3, and local history is kept less about a day back.
I think I went through all the settings, but can't find where I can increase this value. Does anyone know where I might find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Modify `bin\idea.exe.vmoptions` (`idea.vmoptions` on Linux, [Info.plist](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-197) on Mac), add the following line:

```
-DlocalHistory.daysToKeep=5
```

It was the only configurable option removed from the settings user interface.

Another way is to use `Help` | `Find Action`, type **Registry** in the box, ensure that `Include non-menu actions` option is enabled, select the **Registry** result from the list, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image: Registry]

Note that the default value is 5 **working** days.

Comment: Awesome answer. 
Didn't know about "Find Action" or the Registry, both seem quite useful in general. Thanks!
I wonder why they removed this option from the settings...

Comment: Nice! From the link you've supplied turns out that the Registry can also be reached by `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + /`

Comment: This shortcut may not work with some keymaps or regional keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 3):

Also you should know that maximum value of this setting **localHistory.daysToKeep** is **23** (working days).
 
If you try set this value more than 23, history just will saved nothing at all (after restart IDEA)!
 
I discovered this by myself by experimental way =)