# Intellij Live Templates in Code Complete list

Tags: intellij-idea

If your familiar with visual studio you can select code snippets from the auto complete list. is this possible in IntelliJ

So for example if i type

```
for
```

it would show "for" and the live template "fori" in the code complete dropdown list

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Turns out it is possible (unless I'm missing something) via the Registry editor:

[image: Registry Screen Capture]

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11829639/579828) on how to get to this editor.

Comment: Awesome find. this will be very helpful. i confirmed that it works. Go to Help > Find Action > tick "Include non-menu actions" > search for Registry> enable the option shown in the image above

Comment: That is a great find indeed, even I was not aware of this option in the registry :)