# Intellij IDEA on mac: how to disable pinch gesture for zooming

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA for scala development on my macbook air. However, there is one very irritating feature: OS-X pinch two fingers to zoom changes the font size. I would like to disable this because it always happens unintentionally. Does anyone knows how to disable it?

Edit: See comments for the solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to disable `Preferences` | `Editor` | `Change font size (Zoom) with Command+Mouse Wheel`.

**EDIT**: it doesn't have effect on the trackpad pinch to zoom, but there is a hack to disable trackpad gestures via the [IDE Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11829639/104891):

> actionSystem.mouseGesturesEnabled = false

Comment: Try to [access the registry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11829639/104891) and disable `actionSystem.mouseGesturesEnabled` property.

Comment: After restarting IDEA it works! Thank you so much CrazyCoder!

Comment: no need for restart in the latest version. thanks @CrazyCoder

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 17):

In addition to the answer by @CrazyCoder above, in order to access this Registry property on Mac OSX (tested on Mavericks):

- at source code area, use the shortcut `Cmd+Opt+Shift+/`
- select the 2nd option `Registry`
- then you can find the attribute `actionSystem.mouseGesturesEnabled`, unclick the value column

Comment: Excellent! this works for me following a restart of IntelliJ and the Registry option is now the 1st option, at least for version 2020.2