# How far back does Intellij's local history go back?

Tags: intellij-idea

I use JetBrains intellij for JavaScript NodeJS development.

I was trying to find some code I haven't committed in Git but have overwritten since couple of weeks ago. How far back and how much detail is Intellij's local history?

Can I find this change ever again?

Comment: Good question.  My guess is that if you don't see it in the local history, then it's gone.

Comment: I was asking on behalf of a friend who was a home worker, so I can't see their screen. I hope it isn't all gone

Comment: I don't know if IntelliJ flushes the history after a certain time, or after a certain number of revisions.  If this work were performed in the past few days, I'd expect it would be there.  Just check.

Comment: Thanks, I'll pass it on. The day the changes were made was 2 weeks ago which is why I'm concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The retention period for local history varies according to the version of IntelliJ.

For example in [2017.x](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/using-local-history.html) and in [2016.x](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/using-local-history.html):

> Local history is cleared when you install a new version of IntelliJ IDEA or when you invalidate caches. Therefore, check in the changes to your version control system before performing these operations.

But in [2018.x](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html) (see the section titled **Retention period for Local History**):

> By default, Local History is configured to store revisions for the last 5 working days (that is, days when the file was modified).

The 2018.x link includes instructions on how to extend the default retention period including this suggestion:

> You can change the default period of how many days local history will be kept for

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11829639/2000323

Comment: I can't find where you got the third quote. Google only finds this answer and no other page on the internet containing that phrase.